# How to create auto symlink in modx?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Is there any solution to create automatically symlinks in subfolder (container) in MODX?

In resources tab I have container "test1" where I create documents (resources) and I need to have automatically created symlink (actually two of even three symlinks) in container "test2" (and "test3" and "test4") with link to this created document (resource)

As result I will have few links:

1. link .../test1/newdocument.html
2. link .../test2/newdocument.html
3. link .../test3/newdocument.html
4. link .../test4/newdocument.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to display that resources also in another folder/directory?

A better approach should be using getresources oder pdoResoureces to display dynamically already existing content.